# Are there any other API's similar to Connect SDK that can allow an Android device to play videos on an Apple TV?

Tags: android, live-connect-sdk

The Android app I'm currently working on can stream to Chromecast and Roku. A feature that needs to be implemented in the near future is the ability to stream to the Apple TV. I just came by this API which allows me to stream files stored on my phone to the Apple TV:

http://www.svlconnectsdk.com/

I was wondering if there are any other similar API's out there? It'd be nice to have some choice to see what I need, before I start integrating it into my app.

Comment: You may find a useful library from the [open-airplay](https://github.com/jamesdlow/open-airplay) list.

Comment: @plátanoplomo Thank you!